# Stata tables/collect confidence interval in one cell

Tags: collections, datatable, stata, collect

I work a lot with the new tables collect command in stata 17. Does anybody know how to get the confidence interval in one cell in the table vs. One column for lower bound and one column for the upper bound estimate?

Alternatively a quick fix in word (or excel though my final document is word. Saving the output in excel takes so long)

Is I see it there is no option to put it in one column, so maybe a layout work around?

Comment: I haven't tried the `collect` command yet but, depending on what other functionality you require, you could try the `table1` package, which by default puts the percentage and confidence intervals in one cell. You can install it using the community-contributed command `ssc install table1`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer :)  We are rewriting the whole code for lots of tables with table/collect so I am really trying to find a fix that works with those commands. If nothing turns up this is alast straw I will try!

Comment: Could you please provide a minimum reproducible example? I have been working a little bit with the new collect and new putdocx commands so I might be able to help. Alternatively try out the Stata forum and do not forget to mark this post as crossposted if you do so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the stata documentation of the collect command, the quick start mentions
`table (colname) (result), command(_r_b _r_ci: regress y x1 x2 x3)`. You should be able to use `collect` with it, but without a minimum reproducible example of your specific case, it is hard to verify if this works as intended in your case. For the general idea of a minimum reproducible example please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and for specific advice on how to create a minimum reproducible example please see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377015/how-to-create-high-quality-reproducible-examples-in-stata).

Here is a general example that uses table, collect and putdocx to create a word document to get the confidence interval in one cell:

```
use https://www.stata-press.com/data/r17/nlsw88.dta
table (colname) (result), command(_r_b _r_ci: regress wage union occupation married age)
collect layout (colname) (result)
putdocx begin
putdocx collect
putdocx save Table, replace
```

Comment: Hey @flxflks thanks so much. I think when I use collect it does not store _r_ci but it stores upper and lower bounds in Dimension results, but I can try and see if I can tell collect to save it with the collect prefix. Howeve I think it might depend on the command and if the command produces that result (confidence interval in one cell) or not. I use lots of descriptives.  Next time I'm at work I will defnitley try it and let you know!

Comment: Hey @Anis. You're welcome. I think a minimum reproducible example is needed to understand what you are trying to do! :)

Comment: hey @flxflks you were right, I dont know how I did not see the _r_ci !

Comment: Perfect! :) And no worries, it happens to the best! :)